# Scala - accessing an implicit class from an anonymous sub-class without the new keyword

Tags: scala, implicit

In the following Scala snippet, my goal is to literally write `Collector { "A" x 123 }` for some class `Collector`. The body of this anonymous sub-class should have access to an implicit `x` that is defined within the class `Collector`.
I tried to achieve this via a companion object and a by-name parameter, but without success.
For now I have to write `new Collector { "A" x 123 }`. Can you find a way to get rid of the `new` keyword here?

```
object TestApp extends App {
  new Collector { "A" x 123 } // works as intended, even without companion object
  Collector { "A" x 123 } // does not compile because no implicit "x" found
}

class Collector { // some class with an individual implicit inner class
  val coll = ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
  implicit class MyImplicit(name: String) { def x(i: Int) = coll += s"$name($i)" }
}

object Collector { // getting rid of the "new" keyword looses access to MyImplicit
  def apply(body: => Unit) = new Collector { body }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collector { "A" x 123 }` does not create an anonymous subclass of `Collector`, it's just a method call. So you can't access `Collector`'s members, implicit or not, in the argument.

Comment: Ah, I see, this is not even related to implicits, but more to closures and by-name parameters. And there is probably no workaround (without macros). Now I see that I tried to "forward" the literal body `{"A" x 123}` along two hops into a different context (that I expected to finally bound the free variables). But it works the other way round: *first* all free variables are bounded at the place where they are literally written, so even if some closure is passed around it always only refers to its original context.